# Angular 2+ best practice

Tags: angular

What is the best practice when developing a CRUD of an entity using an API Rest in terms of refreshing the data.
Basically we have a list of elements in a main screen and insert a new element from a modal, which is the best way to update the list with the new element?, insert it locally or call the API again to have the list again of the server?

Comment: There's no need to call the server again, since you know already what the new data is. It is best to insert it locally once you've verified that the new data creation has been successful. Typically, you want to limit server calls as much as possible, since it doesn't make sense to go fetch, say, 30,000 records again, when all you did was create one (that's an extreme example, but what I want to point out is how performance of the app will suffer). However, there are certain situations where it may be necessary to perform a server call. But generally speaking, you want to limit server calls

Comment: Ok, I think the same, but in a discussion about this, the reasoning to re-invoke the API was the possibility that someone else was working with the same list in another place, then both would see outdated lists. But I think that re-invoking the API does not solve that problem, to make it perfect I think we should have reverse communication from the server with sockets.

Comment: Yes you would use sockets in that situation, which is independent of the rest services, which would end up doing a server call. In that case, yes, it is appropriate and the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main concern is syncing your client with the server without polling.
If it's the case you can use a `Web Push notification service`, such as [oneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk).
It works like this,

1) you create an app on OneSignal

2) you get a playerId by registering your client on OneSignal (clientside job), then send the playerId to your server and store It for further lookup.

3) whenever you have some data change on your server, you [send](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-example-code-create-notification) `silent background notifications` to your clients  (by means of an api) referencing them with their playerIds or some tags that you set and on the client side  getting the data.